# Is it possible to manipulate the position of the Domain axis in a JFreeChart plot?

Tags: jfreechart

I have a dataset that I want to display as a pair of histograms/barcharts. One set of data, I want to display as a "positive" set of values rising upwards. The second set, I need to display as a "negative" set, descending. They share a domain axis.

I can draw them as I want in all using a CombinedDomainCategoryPlot but for one important detail - the axis appears below the second plot, whereas I would like it to appear in the middle between the two plots.

For the record, these data are sequence tags that have been mapped against a genome sequence. Some map to the "top" strand of the genome and others to the "bottom" or "reverse" strand, so the point of the visualisation is to represent the data in that fashion. I had hoped to be able simply to reverse the bottom plot value axis and have the domain axis appear in the middle, but it appears not to work that way.

My assumption is that I will have to subclass or replace the CombinedDomainCategoryPlot class, but if someone else has already found a way around this or knows how to do it properly within the current confines of the code than I would be grateful. Again, for the record, I am working with version 1.0.12 of JFreeChart (because of maven dependency brokenness with the "current" version 1.0.13). Sadly the JFreeChart forums appear to be dead too.

Comment: What have you tried in code? Try creating the two subplots, add them to the combined and set the axises AFTER the plots have been added to the combined.

Comment: @Jes Doh! That's brilliant. I sat and stared at the code for 20 minutes this morning and read the line where the subplots get their axes set to null when they get added to the combined plot and never once thought to add it back in to one or other subplot.

Comment: I'll just post the complete explaination then ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the `CombinedDomainCategoryPlot` resets the domain on the subplot added. From `CombinedDomainCategoryPlot.java`:

```
public void add(CategoryPlot subplot, int weight) {
  // [..] omitted code
  subplot.setDomainAxis(null);
  // [..] omitted code
}
```

The solution is simply to set the domain axis after you have added the subplot:

```
CombinedDomainCategoryPlot mainPlot = // your plot;
CategoryAxis axis = // the axis you want to use.
CategoryPlot subPlot // the subplot in question
mainPlot.add(subPlot);
subPlot.setDomainAxis(axis);
```